# Trying to use the STHorizontalPicker Library from GitHub but getting multiple errors

Tags: iphone, github, picker

I'm trying to use the open source [STHorizontalPicker library](https://github.com/stackthread/STHorizontalPicker) to implement a horizontal picker to my project but when importing the .m and .h files from GitHub to my project I'm getting multiple errors when compiling.

Does it require any special implementation?

I'm simply copying the .h and .m and adding to the project. Error are like : property 'cornerRatius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'...

Do I have to import some class to those files ?

Thnaks in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to import some class to those files?

Yes, you'll need Quartz.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for the fast answer, I added the QuartzCore component and thing progressed. Although, now I'm having other problems compiling the project. Do you have any working example of this implementation.?